# Theory of structures with infinite Partial orders. $\langle H, \{\sqsubset_i \}_{i\in I} \rangle$

Tags: reference-request, order-theory

My recent interests have led me to have to deal with particular structures I have never seen before. Sets equipped with an infinite numbers of partial orders $\{\sqsubset_i:i\in I\}$.

I'm a bit confused and I don't know what is the notation when we work with these kind of constructions but I mean something like:

$\langle H, \sqsubset_1,\sqsubset_2,...,\sqsubset_i \rangle$ but I don't know if is correct because we have infinite partial orders.

or $\{\langle H, \sqsubset_i \rangle:i\in I\}$ we have a set of partial order structures on $H$.

I already know that there are infinite partial orders on every set, but I'm asking if

> Do exists a theory that studies sets structured by and infinite set of
>   partial orders as single objects, where are explored requirements and
>   derived theorems?

*We have something similar for example when we pass from structures with one binary operation to fields and rings and in general sets equipped with two binary operations.*

**Update**

Using this [notation](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struttura_%28matematica%29) (if I understand well) we can denote this structure with

$\mathfrak H=\langle H, \{\sqsubset_i \}_{i\in I} \rangle$ and $|I|\ge \aleph_0$

**UPDATE**: To be more specific that is an **example** of what kind of structures I'm talking about:

*For every infinite set $H$ I have a set of relations $\{\sqsubset_a:a\in H\}$ that are strict partial orders on $H$.*

with that properties:

$i)$ if $\forall a,b(a,b\in H)(a\neq b)$ than $\sqsubset_a \cap\sqsubset_b=\varnothing$

$ii)$ $\forall a(a\in H)$ and $\forall A \in \mathcal P(H)$ if $ a \in A$ then $a$ is the $\sqsubset_a$-minimal element of $A$

To be more clear here an important comment of Kevin Carlson

> *"Surely such things are used somewhere in the wide world of human endeavor. I don't know where. But the orders must definitely interact
>   in well-defined ways in any field where they're found to be useful, or
>   as we've both observed the structures are too general to be of
>   interest."*

Well the question is about an axiomatic study of these kind of structures and example of compatible properties that are already useful in some field of mathematics.

**UPDATE**: I just discovered about Multi-ordered Posets as sets equipped with a finite number of partial order relations in [Bishop, Killpatrick MULTI-ORDERED POSETS](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/h6/h6.pdf)

A definition is given and these structures are introduced to generalize the concept of differential posets: this is one kind of structure I am interested in but the topic is too much advanced for me and the goal of the paper is not very interesting too (for me)...but there are not external references to these structures in this paper or to an introduction and is what I am searching for.

Comment: Are there any known relations between the given partial orders on $H$?

Comment: @ArthurFischer I don't know if is important to say the properties of my particular structure here, becuase I wanted to find the more general results as possible about these structures. but my structure have some properties:

Comment: @ArthurFischer 

A) for example I know (I'm still studyng it) that different elements induces different partial orders (aka one is not a sub order of another and it does hold for some elements, but I don't have a proof that all the relations are pairwise disjoint). and 
B) for every subset $A\in H$ and for all $a\in H$ if $a\in A$ then in $\langle A, \sqsubset_a \rangle$ the smaller element is $a$.

Comment: @ArthurFischer now that I read again my second comment seems me a bit unclear, but I mean that my structure is equipped form a set of p.orders $\{ \sqsubset_a : a\in H\}$ and if $a\neq b$ then $\sqsubset_a\neq \sqsubset_b$

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking for. As you say, it's easy to endow any infinite set with infinitely many distinct partial orders, so there's no way to expect any non-trivial results in general. Certainly such structures are perfectly allowable in model theory, though I can't tell whether that's how you're using the word "structure." Your $\mathfrak{H}$ notation is fine. So I can be a tiny bit useful, note your relations are certainly not pairwise disjoint, since partial orders are reflexive.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I was wrong, in my structure the are strict partial orders, so not reflexive, but this is only my example.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Anyways the question can be more clear if you think about Rings and fields analogy, I know that there are infinite binary operations on a set so the study of binary operations on a set started allowing one operation (magmas, groups and others) the allowing two operations (rings, fields and others) adding axioms, In order theory we have order sets, posets that are ordered structures (one p-order relation) I'm asking if in some fields are used sets with infinite p.order defined on it, or something like that.

Comment: Surely such things are used somewhere in the wide world of human endeavor. I don't know where. But the orders must definitely interact in well-defined ways in any field where they're found to be useful, or as we've both observed the structures are too general to be of interest. You see this is also the case for rings and fields: having relations or operations on a set that aren't connected is useless. Perhaps you should tell us more about the particular context in which these structures came up for you.

Comment: @KevinCarlson "But the orders must definitely interact in well-defined ways in any field where they're found to be useful" yes you hitted the point!, so my question was asking for examples of well-defined structures of "compatible" orders.

Comment: Isn't condition ii) simply that each $a\in H$ is the $\sqsubset_a$-minimal element of $H$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes it is.. but I was unsure to write that so easy (like you did) because i'm talking about partial orders, and for every $\sqsubset_a$ exists a subset of $H$ without a minimal element ("rootles tree").

Comment: @MphLee Ah, do you mean *a* minimal (no other is smaller) or *the* smallest (smaller than all others)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm sorry, but I'm still learning the right terminology: What I mean $1)$ is that $a$ is *minimal* for $\sqsubset_a$ (do not exist a $p$ such that $p\sqsubset_a a$), $2)$ in $H$ we have that $a$ is the only *minimal* element of $\sqsubset_a$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh! I'm very sorry Now that i read better, what I wrote on $ii$) does not make any sense, I must edit, Is not for every subset, Is just that $a$ is the only $\sqsubset_a$-minimal element $H$

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this helps but if for each $a \in H$ we define
$$\sqsubset_{a} = \{ (a,b) \colon b \in H \text{ and } a \neq b \} $$
then we get a family of strict partial orders that satisfy your conditions. This demonstrates consistency. No claim is made for usefulness of this example.

Comment: yes, this satisfies my conditions, but mine was only an example. So your example can be usefull if you know the name of this order, or if this kind of families of strict partial orders are usefull in some field of mathematics. Where are these structures used often?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the family of partial orders I described has no customary name. I just made it up. I can't think of a place where one would want the pairwise disjointness of the (strict) partial orders. Basically you are saying you have a bunch of partial orders that have nothing to do with one another. I don't know that one can do much in that situation. This is just my opinion which might not be worth much.